host command -W timeout not working
The linux host command says capital -W specifies wait seconds, but in my case it always seems to wait longer regardless of specified seconds:
time host -W 2 2409:8a50:4be:3eb0:5cce:db14:2e63:daf6
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

real    0m6.008s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.004s

I could forcely kill it with timeout -k 3 3 [initial command here], but I could use that timed out erorr reply; and still, why is the -W not working ?
Usage: host [-aCdilrTvVw] [-c class] [-N ndots] [-t type] [-W time]
            [-R number] [-m flag] hostname [server]
       -a is equivalent to -v -t ANY
       -c specifies query class for non-IN data
       -C compares SOA records on authoritative nameservers
       -d is equivalent to -v
       -i IP6.INT reverse lookups
       -l lists all hosts in a domain, using AXFR
       -m set memory debugging flag (trace|record|usage)
       -N changes the number of dots allowed before root lookup is done
       -p specifies the port on the server to query
       -r disables recursive processing
       -R specifies number of retries for UDP packets
       -s a SERVFAIL response should stop query
       -t specifies the query type
       -T enables TCP/IP mode
       -U enables UDP mode
       -v enables verbose output
       -V print version number and exit
       -w specifies to wait forever for a reply
       -W specifies how long to wait for a reply  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
       -4 use IPv4 query transport only
       -6 use IPv6 query transport only


There are two reason for that:

There's probably more than a single nameserver line in /etc/resolv.conf.

Notice the -R ("specifies number of retries for UDP packets") flag. The man pages say:

If number is negative or zero, the number of retries will default to 1. The default value is 1.

So it will always have at least 1 retry.


From couple of testing, it appears that when there's more than a single nameserver defined in /etc/resolv.conf, the timeout -W applies only on the last one. The rest of them will have a timeout of 1.
So if you have 2 nameservers defined in your resolv.conf, here what will happen:

Connect to the first name server, wait for response for 1 second.
After the timeout, connect to the second name server, this time wait for the -W value - 2 seconds.
Repeat steps 1-2 at least one time (or more if -R is provided and is higher than 1), or until you get some response.

That explains the 6 seconds.
